# Restart SKEmitterNode without removing particles

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skemitternode

I have a particle effect for a muzzle flare set up. What I'm currently using is a low numParticlesToEmit to limit the emitter to a short burst, and doing resetSimulation() on the emitter whenever I want to start a new burst of particles.

The problem I'm having is that resetSimulation() removes all particles onscreen, and I often need to create a new burst of particles before the previous particles disappear normally so they get erased early.

Is there a clean way start up the emitter again without erasing the particles already onscreen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally particle systems have a feature missing from SKEmitters: a duration. This controls how long a system emits. I don't see this in `SKEmitter`, despite being in [`SCNParticleSystems`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnparticlesystem)

**Never mind, a work around:**

SKEmitters have a [`numParticlesToEmit`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skemitternode/1398043-numparticlestoemit) property and a [`particleBirthRate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skemitternode/1398039-particlebirthrate). Combined, these determine how long the particle system emits before shutting down.

Using these as a control of the emission it's possible to create pulses of particles emitted in the way you want for something like a muzzle flash or explosion.

I'm not sure if it remvoes itself when it reaches this limit. If not, you'll have to create a removal function of some sort. Because the way to get your desired effect (multiple muzzle flashes on screen) is to `copy()` the `SKEmitter`. This is quite efficient, so don't worry about overhead.

Comment: Yeah, that works well. A quick SKAction sequence of wait then removeFromParent handles removal well enough.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `targetNode` on SKEmitters that are suppose to move the particles to another node so that when you reset the emitter, the previous particles still stay.  Unfortunately, this is still bugged from what I can tell, unless somebody else has figured out how to get it working and I just missed it.  Keep this in mind though in case they do ever fix it.

Comment: btw, SCNPlanes with an SKScene of particles will work for your problem of needing two instances of the same particle in multiple positions/views. The only trick, getting the SCNScene into your SKScene.

Comment: That requires sk3dnode  already knew about it, but it is an insane mess rendering that

Answer (score 0):

Hi to help future readers, the code that I use to calculate the duration of the emitter is this:

`let duration = Double(emitter.numParticlesToEmit) / Double(emitter.particleBirthRate) + Double(emitter.particleLifetime + emitter.particleLifetimeRange/2)`

It works perfectly for me

Extension:

```
extension SKEmitterNode {
    var emitterDuration: Double {
        return Double(numParticlesToEmit) / Double(particleBirthRate) + Double(particleLifetime + particleLifetimeRange/2)
    }
}
```